# Android Intent-Filter Only Launches App When Email Sent from Some Client Sender Apps

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments, intentfilter

my app's file-intent handles attachments with a custom file extension in emails sent from aol.com, but not from Thunderbird. Has anyone had this issue? I see some comments on mime-type handling. My file type is basically text with a ".hmrx" extension.

Is this a matter of adding something more to the intent-filter?

I don't want my app to be suggested for handling general text files... I don't see the problem:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.hmrx" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.hmrx" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.hmrx" />
        </intent-filter>
```

EDIT:

By the way, I tried adding

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.hmrx" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But then it offers to open regular text files with my app.. which I dont want.

Apparently this is happening because Thunderbird send just about any kind of text as inline instead of as a "real" attachment. Anybody successfully managed this?

Thanks